# Implementing large number of points Beier and Neely's Image Warping Method in JavaScript and WebGL

Tags: javascript, html, image-processing, glsl, webgl

I'm attempting to implement Beier and Neely's method for image warping using JavaScript and WebGL (like [this](https://chenxing.name/fun/imgwarp-js/) as an example, and described in detail [here](https://cs.brown.edu/courses/csci1950-g/results/proj5/edwallac/)). The goal is to distort facial images by allowing the user to interactively move points around on a canvas. Each point would manipulate the image as per the algorithm described.

So far, I've managed to create a WebGL program that allows users to interact with an image by clicking and dragging points on the image, and I have successfully set up the basic image distortion effect.

At this point, I have implemented a basic version of the algorithm allowing for up to 32 "points" (which get calculated to lines) at a time, although ultimately I want to be able to use it to match with other facial tracking information, so I want to allow for hundreds /a dynamic amount.

Created an interactive canvas with movable points.
Applied a basic distortion effect that manipulates the image around these points.

Resolved an issue with the distortion effect being offset from the mouse cursor.

implemented a basic distortion method of Beier and Neely with a limited, small number of points that fit in the WebGL uniform.

Remaining challenges:
create the effect with hundreds of points, possibly in a GLSL texture, although I'm struggling with the implementation of that, considering that the uniforms only allow for a small limit of points at a time, and I also need to allow for a dynamic number of them.

Also keep in mind that the ultimate goal is to be able to track points from one face (have done in different project, getting landmarks using tensor flow) to be able to influence the face of a picture, so if anyone has any better suggestions for better distortion algorithms besides for this one, that that would be accepted as well.

Here is the current state of my code (view in full screen if u try big images):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gl-matrix/2.8.1/gl-matrix-min.js"></script>

<button id="sl">Select Image</button>
<br>
<button id="editMode">Enter point edit mode</button>
<button id="point" disabled>Add warp point</button>
<br>
<h4>Add at least 3 points</h4><br>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<style>
    .warpPoint {
        display:inline-block;
        border-radius:50%;
        border:1px solid black;
        background:gold;
        position:absolute;
        width: 10px;
        height: 10px;
    }

    .warpPoint:hover {
        cursor:pointer;
    }
</style>

<script>
let warpPoints = [];
let warpPointsFlat = [];
let warpPointCount = 0;
let isAddingPoints = false;
let img = new Image();
let resolution = vec2.create();
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let warpPointCountLoc;
let sl = document.getElementById('sl');
let editMode = document.getElementById('editMode');
let point = document.getElementById('point');
let program, gl, imageLoc, resolutionLoc, texture;
let warpPointsLocs = [];

let imageSamplerLoc;


// Initial resolution values
resolution[0] = canvas.width;
resolution[1] = canvas.height;

// Warp point
let warpPoint = vec2.create();

// Functions
function mouseMoveHandler(e, warpPoint, origX, origY, startX, startY) {
    let newX = origX + e.clientX - startX;
    let newY = origY + e.clientY - startY;

    // Account for the canvas' offset from the top-left of the viewport
    newX -= canvas.offsetLeft;
    newY -= canvas.offsetTop;

    warpPoint.setPosition(newX, newY);

    var newX_gl;
    var newY_gl;
    newX_gl = newX / resolution[0]; // Convert to UV coordinates
    newY_gl = 1 - newY / resolution[1]; // Convert to UV coordinates

    warpPoints[warpPoint.index] = vec4.fromValues(newX_gl, newY_gl, 0.46, 0.2); // Use vec4 and include strength and radius

    warpPointsFlat = updateWarpPointsFlat(warpPoints);
    render();
}



function WarpPoint(index) {
    this.index = index;
    this.el = document.createElement("div");
    this.el.className = "warpPoint";
    // In the WarpPoint setPosition function:
    // In the WarpPoint setPosition function:
    this.setPosition = function(x, y) {
        this.el.style.left = `${x + canvas.offsetLeft}px`;
        this.el.style.top = `${y + canvas.offsetTop}px`;

        this.x = x / resolution[0]; // Convert to UV coordinates
        this.y = 1 - y / resolution[1];
        warpPoints[this.index] = vec4.fromValues(this.x, this.y, 0.1, 0.1); // Use vec4 to include z (strength) and w (radius)

        warpPointsFlat = updateWarpPointsFlat(warpPoints);
        render(); // Make sure to rerender when a warp point is moved
    };

    document.body.appendChild(this.el);

    this.el.onmousedown = (e) => {
        var startX = e.clientX;
        var startY = e.clientY;
        var origX = this.el.offsetLeft;
        var origY = this.el.offsetTop;

        var mouseMoveHandlerBind = (e) => {
            mouseMoveHandler(e, this, origX, origY, startX, startY);
        };
        var mouseUpHandler = () => {
            document.removeEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveHandlerBind);
            document.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpHandler);
        };

        document.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveHandlerBind);
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpHandler);
    };
}


editMode.onclick = () =>{
    if(isAddingPoints) {
        point.disabled = true;
        isAddingPoints = false;
        editMode.innerHTML = "entered WARP mode. Click again to edit"
    } else {
        point.disabled = false;
        isAddingPoints = true;
        editMode.innerHTML = "entered EDIT mode. Click again to warp"
    }
}


function updateWarpPointsFlat(warpPoints) {
    let warpPointsFlat = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < warpPoints.length; i++) {
        warpPointsFlat.push(warpPoints[i][0]);
        warpPointsFlat.push(warpPoints[i][1]);
        warpPointsFlat.push(warpPoints[i][2]); // Z
        warpPointsFlat.push(warpPoints[i][3]); // W
    }
    return new Float32Array(warpPointsFlat);
}
point.onclick=addWarpPoint;
function addWarpPoint() {
    warpPoints.push(vec4.fromValues(0, 0, 0.1, 0.1));
    var warpPoint = new WarpPoint(warpPoints.length - 1); // pass index
    let x = (canvas.width / 2);
    let y = (canvas.height / 2);

    warpPoint.setPosition(x, y);

    warpPointCount = warpPoints.length;
    warpPointsFlat = updateWarpPointsFlat(warpPoints);

    console.log("Warp point added. Current warp points: ", warpPoints);
}

function loadImage(url, callback) {
    let image = new Image();
    image.src = url;
    image.onload = () => callback(image);
}

function createShader(type, source) {
    let shader = gl.createShader(type);
    gl.shaderSource(shader, source);
    gl.compileShader(shader);
    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
        console.error('Error compiling shader:', gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
        gl.deleteShader(shader);
        return null;
    }
    return shader;
}

function createProgram(vertexShader, fragmentShader) {
    let program = gl.createProgram();
    gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
    gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
    gl.linkProgram(program);
    if (!gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
        console.error('Error linking program:', gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
        gl.deleteProgram(program);
        return null;
    }
    return program;
}

function createTexture(image) {
    let texture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    return texture;
}

function resizeCanvas() {
    canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth;
    canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight;
    resolution[0] = canvas.width;
    resolution[1] = canvas.height;
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
}

// In the render function:
function render() {
    // Clear the canvas
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.useProgram(program);

    // Update uniforms
    gl.uniform2fv(resolutionLoc, resolution);

    // Set up the viewport
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

    // Update uniforms
    let warpPointCountUniformLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'warpPointCount');
    let warpPointsUniformLoc = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        warpPointsUniformLoc[i] = gl.getUniformLocation(program, `warpPoints[${i}]`);
    }

    gl.uniform1i(warpPointCountUniformLoc, warpPointCount);

    // If there are warp points, pass them to the shader
    if(warpPointsFlat.length > 0) {
        for(let i = 0; i < warpPointCount; i++) {
            gl.uniform2fv(warpPointsUniformLoc[i], [warpPointsFlat[i * 4], warpPointsFlat[i * 4 + 1]]);
        }
    }

    // Always bind texture and draw image, regardless of warp point count
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.uniform1i(imageSamplerLoc, 0);

    // Draw primitives
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

}


window.onload = function() {
    console.log("hi!")
    let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    gl = canvas.getContext("webgl")
    let vertexShader = createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER, `
        attribute vec2 position;
        varying vec2 uv;
        void main() {
            uv = position * 0.5 + 0.5;
            gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
        }
    `);
    let fragmentShader = createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, `
    precision mediump float;

    uniform vec2 resolution;
    uniform sampler2D u_image;
    uniform vec2 warpPoints[32];  
    uniform int warpPointCount;  
    uniform float alpha;

    void main() {
    vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution.xy;
    vec2 pos = uv;

    vec2 displacement = vec2(0.0);
    float weightSum = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i += 2) {
        if(i >= warpPointCount) break;

        vec2 P = warpPoints[i].xy;
        vec2 Q = warpPoints[i+1].xy;

        float dist_PQ = distance(P, Q);
        vec2 dir_PQ = normalize(Q - P);

        vec2 X_P = uv - P;
        float u = dot(X_P, dir_PQ);
        float v = length(cross(vec3(dir_PQ, 0.0), vec3(X_P, 0.0)));

        vec2 P_prime = P + u * dir_PQ;
        vec2 Q_prime = Q + v * dir_PQ;

        vec2 displacement_this_line = P_prime - uv;
        float weight_this_line = pow(dist_PQ, alpha) / (0.001 + dot(X_P, X_P));

        displacement += weight_this_line * displacement_this_line;
        weightSum += weight_this_line;
    }

    if (weightSum != 0.0) {
        displacement /= weightSum;
    }

    pos += displacement;

    vec4 color = texture2D(u_image, clamp(pos, 0.0, 1.0));
    gl_FragColor = color;
    }

    `);

    program = createProgram(vertexShader, fragmentShader);
    gl.useProgram(program);
    gl.uniform2fv(resolutionLoc, resolution);

    imageSamplerLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'u_image');

    // Fetch warp point uniform locations
    for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        warpPointsLocs[i] = gl.getUniformLocation(program, `warpPoints[${i}]`);
    }

    

    let positionLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'position');
    resolutionLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'resolution');
    warpPointCountLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'warpPointCount');
    imageLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'image');

    
    let positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
        -1.0, -1.0,
        1.0, -1.0,
        -1.0, 1.0,
        -1.0, 1.0,
        1.0, -1.0,
        1.0, 1.0
    ]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);


    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLoc);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLoc, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    
};

window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    resizeCanvas();
    render();
});

sl.onclick = () => {
    
    var inp = document.createElement("input")
    inp.type="file"
    inp.onchange=()=>{
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(
            inp.files[0]
        )
        img.src=url;
        img.onload = () => {
            texture = createTexture(img);
            canvas.width=img.width;
            canvas.height=img.height
            resizeCanvas();
            render();
        };
    }
    inp.click()
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Coordinates is the key!

In your code, you do multiple conventions between screen and GL, and they are not quite right.

Since your `canvas` exists on the HTML page it has its position relative to the page. The same situation with the warp points. Therefore, to convert coordinate from page to GL coords you have to get into account not only position of the warp point but also its distance from the corner of the `canvas`.

Things get even trickier because in shader, texture starts at the left-bottom corner (i.e. it is 0:0 in shader), but for the rectangle on the screen, it is `offsetLeft:offsetTop + offsetHeight`

The last thing is that the warping formula doesn't look right to me, but I will leave it with you because the main request was to make shader react properly on warp points.

Please let me know if this helps.

```js
        // moved to constants for testing
        const STRENGTH = 0.2;
        const RADIUS = 50.0 / 300.0;
        
        let warpPoints = [];
        let warpPointsFlat = [];
        let warpPointCount = 0;
        let isEditing = false;
        let img = new Image();
        let resolution = vec2.create();
        let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        let warpPointCountLoc;
        let sl = document.getElementById('sl');
        let editMode = document.getElementById('editMode');
        let point = document.getElementById('point');
        let program, gl, imageLoc, resolutionLoc, texture;
        console.log(888)

        // Initial resolution values
        resolution[0] = canvas.clientWidth;
        resolution[1] = canvas.clientHeight;

        // Warp point
        let warpPoint = vec2.create();

        // Functions
        // Functions
        function mouseMoveHandler(e, warpPoint, origX, origY, startX, startY) {
            let newX = origX + e.clientX - startX;
            let newY = origY + e.clientY - startY;
            warpPoint.setPosition(newX, newY);
            var newX_gl;
            var newY_gl;
            if (!isEditing) {
                let newX_gl = (newX - canvas.offsetLeft) / resolution[0];
                let newY_gl = ((canvas.offsetTop + canvas.offsetHeight) - newY) / resolution[1];
                warpPoints[warpPoint.index] = vec4.fromValues(newX_gl, newY_gl, STRENGTH, RADIUS); // Use vec4 and include strength and radius

                warpPointsFlat = updateWarpPointsFlat(warpPoints);
                render();
            }
        }

        function WarpPoint(index) {
            this.index = index;
            this.el = document.createElement("div");
            this.el.className = "warpPoint";

            this.setPosition = function (x, y) {
                this.el.style.left = `${x}px`;
                this.el.style.top = `${y}px`;

                let x_gl = (x - canvas.offsetLeft) / resolution[0];
                let y_gl = ((canvas.offsetTop + canvas.offsetHeight) - y) / resolution[1];
                warpPoints[this.index] = vec4.fromValues(x_gl, y_gl, STRENGTH, RADIUS); // Use vec4 to include z (strength) and w (radius)

                warpPointsFlat = updateWarpPointsFlat(warpPoints);
            };

            document.body.appendChild(this.el);

            this.el.onmousedown = (e) => {
                var startX = e.clientX;
                var startY = e.clientY;
                var origX = this.el.offsetLeft;
                var origY = this.el.offsetTop;

                var mouseMoveHandlerBind = (e) => {
                    mouseMoveHandler(e, this, origX, origY, startX, startY);
                };
                var mouseUpHandler = () => {
                    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveHandlerBind);
                    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpHandler);
                };

                document.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveHandlerBind);
                document.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpHandler);
            };
        }

        editMode.onclick = () => {
            if (isEditing) {
                point.disabled = true;
                isEditing = false;
                editMode.innerHTML = "entered WARP mode. Click again to edit"
            } else {
                point.disabled = false;
                isEditing = true;
                editMode.innerHTML = "entered EDIT mode. Click again to warp"
            }
        }


        function updateWarpPointsFlat(warpPoints) {
            let warpPointsFlat = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < warpPoints.length; i++) {
                warpPointsFlat.push(warpPoints[i][0]);
                warpPointsFlat.push(warpPoints[i][1]);
                warpPointsFlat.push(STRENGTH); // strength
                warpPointsFlat.push(RADIUS); // radius
            }
            return new Float32Array(warpPointsFlat);
        }
        point.onclick = addWarpPoint;
        function addWarpPoint() {
            warpPoints.push(vec4.fromValues(0, 0, STRENGTH, RADIUS));
            var warpPoint = new WarpPoint(warpPoints.length - 1); // pass index
            let x = canvas.width / 2;
            let y = canvas.height / 2;
            warpPoint.setPosition(x, y);

            warpPointCount = warpPoints.length;
            warpPointsFlat = updateWarpPointsFlat(warpPoints);
            console.log("Warp point added. Current warp points: ", warpPoints);
        }

        function loadImage(url, callback) {
            let image = new Image();
            image.src = url;
            image.onload = () => callback(image);
        }

        function createShader(type, source) {
            let shader = gl.createShader(type);
            gl.shaderSource(shader, source);
            gl.compileShader(shader);
            if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
                console.error('Error compiling shader:', gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
                gl.deleteShader(shader);
                return null;
            }
            return shader;
        }

        function createProgram(vertexShader, fragmentShader) {
            let program = gl.createProgram();
            gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
            gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
            gl.linkProgram(program);
            if (!gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
                console.error('Error linking program:', gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
                gl.deleteProgram(program);
                return null;
            }
            return program;
        }

        function createTexture(image) {
            let texture = gl.createTexture();
            gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
            gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
            gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
            gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
            gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
            gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            return texture;
        }

        function resizeCanvas() {
            canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth;
            canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight;
            resolution[0] = canvas.width;
            resolution[1] = canvas.height;
            gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
        }

        function render() {
            gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            gl.useProgram(program);

            gl.uniform2fv(resolutionLoc, resolution);

            // If warp points are present, update uniform data
            if (warpPointsFlat.length > 0) {
                for (let i = 0; i < warpPointCount; i++) {
                    let offset = i * 4;
                    let warpPoint_i_Location = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'warpPoints[' + i + ']');
                    gl.uniform4fv(warpPoint_i_Location, warpPointsFlat.subarray(offset, offset + 4));
                }
            }

            gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
            gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);

            gl.uniform1i(imageLoc, 0);
            gl.uniform1i(warpPointCountLoc, warpPointCount);

            gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

            console.log("(at end of render..)Rendering with resolution: ", resolution);
            console.log("Rendering with warp points: ", warpPointsFlat);
            console.log("Rendering with warp point count (end of render..): ", warpPointCount);
        }
        console.log("ok")
        window.onload = function () {
            console.log("hi!")
            let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
            gl = canvas.getContext("webgl")
            console.log(gl, 22)
            let vertexShader = createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER, `
            attribute vec2 position;
            varying vec2 uv;
            void main() {
                uv = position * 0.5 + 0.5;
                gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
            }
        `);

            let fragmentShader = createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, `
            precision mediump float;
            const int MAX_WARP_POINTS = 10;
            uniform vec2 resolution;
            uniform vec4 warpPoints[MAX_WARP_POINTS];
            uniform int warpPointCount;
            uniform sampler2D image;
            varying vec2 uv;

            void main() {
                vec2 pos = uv;
                vec2 newPos = pos;
                for(int i = 0; i < MAX_WARP_POINTS; i++) {
                    if(i >= warpPointCount) {
                        break;
                    }
                    vec2 warpPoint = warpPoints[i].xy;
                    vec2 offset = warpPoint - pos;
                    float dist = length(offset);
                    vec2 direction = offset / dist;
                    float strength = warpPoints[i].z;
                    float radius = warpPoints[i].w;
                    if (dist < radius) {
                        newPos -= strength * direction * (1.0 - smoothstep(0.0, radius, dist));
                    }
                }
                gl_FragColor = texture2D(image, newPos);
            }
        `);

            program = createProgram(vertexShader, fragmentShader);

            let positionLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'position');
            resolutionLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'resolution');
            warpPointCountLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'warpPointCount');
            imageLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'image');

            let positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
            gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
                -1.0, -1.0,
                1.0, -1.0,
                -1.0, 1.0,
                -1.0, 1.0,
                1.0, -1.0,
                1.0, 1.0
            ]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

            gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLoc);
            gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLoc, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        };

        window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
            resizeCanvas();
            render();
        });

        sl.onclick = () => {
            console.log(2)
            var inp = document.createElement("input")
            inp.type = "file"
            inp.onchange = () => {
                var url = URL.createObjectURL(
                    inp.files[0]
                )
                img.src = url;
                img.onload = () => {
                    texture = createTexture(img);
                    resizeCanvas();
                    render();
                };
            }
            inp.click()
        }
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gl-matrix/2.8.1/gl-matrix-min.js"></script>

    <button id="sl">Select Image</button>
    <br>
    <button id="editMode">Enter point edit mode</button>
    <button id="point" disabled>Add warp point</button>
    <br>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <style>
        .warpPoint {
            display: inline-block;
            border-radius: 50%;
            border: 1px solid black;
            background: gold;
            position: absolute;
            width: 10px;
            height: 10px;
        }

        .warpPoint:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
```

Comment: Click "Full page" after clicking on "Run code snippet". Logging takes too much space and doesn't allow to see an image.

Comment: Thanks! This solves half of the problem! I gave an upvote but it doesn't count at the moment, but when I get more rep I'll upvote it. Yes that was definitely half the issue, which is good now. thanks

Comment: @ChassidusAI let me see if I can improve warping :)

Comment: looking forward

Comment: @ChassidusAI allright, so the key problem now is that there is only one set of warp points that reflects their current positions. However, for warping, we need two sets - original and modified and then distort the image based on how far the modified warp points were moved relative to their original positions. This will require quite massive changes to the code, pretty much in every piece of it. I may get back to this later.

Comment: see edit :) got it mostly working, now just struggling with larger amount of points

Comment: Hmm... looks cool but acts in a bit unpredictable way. At least, I'm not sure how to get the desired result 

Comment: @ChassidusAI, since I helped you to fix the main issues with coordinates and my answer helped you to get very close to the final solution, would you mind picking my answer as a solution?